# Django Error Messages

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am new in Django and i have one problem.

Using django forms and can not get error message in cycle.
They just does not appear. I don't know why this happens but i have changed generating  of  form. In short look to code

```
<span id="username" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.username }} {{ form.username.label_tag }}</span>
<span id="first_name" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.first_name }} {{ form.first_name.label_tag }}</span>
<span id="last_name" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.last_name }} {{ form.last_name.label_tag }}</span>
<span id="email" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.email }} {{ form.email.label_tag }}</span>
<span id="password" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.password1 }} {{ form.password1.label_tag }}</span>
<span id="password2" class="input input--madoka">{{ form.password2 }} {{ form.password2.label_tag }}</span>

{% for error in form.errors %}
     <h2 style="color: red; font-size: 50px">{{ error }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

View:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, '<p class="success-m animated fadeInUp">You were successfully registered  %s </p>'%user.first_name)
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Just error messages does not appear.

Thanks in advance. (Sorry if i gave question wrong.) Beginner :(

Comment: show your view code please

Comment: ok i will add my view code

Comment: what about form data are the they remain, did you see it in front or reset after post action?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have no other condition for the invalid form, it should be:

```
def signup(request):
    template_name = 'signup.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ...
        else:
            # your invalid form after `request.POST` goes here.
            # you should render the template again.
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```